# Extracting string up to first digit in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

I would like to find a straightforward method to extract the portion of a string up to where the first digit appears (possibly using regular expressions instead of traversing the string character by character). I am using this to extract package names from `rpm -qa` without their versions. E.g:

```
Parsing: perl-Text-ParseWords-3.30-1.fc22.i686
Result: perl-Text-ParseWords
```

Comment: Your example cut at `-` not digits.

Comment: There is another `-` after 30

Comment: I think he means if you cut where the first digit appears you will end up with the last `-` character. If the name of the package doesn't have any numbers you could use:

`strtocut="perl-Text-ParseWords-3.30-1.fc22.i686"; echo ${strtocut:0:$(($(expr match "$strtocut" '[A-Za-z-]*')-1))}`

This will use `expr match` to find the length of the string containing only characters from A-Z, a-z and "-". Then it will subtract 1 of that length and extract this portion of the string. Not really reliable though, if the name of the package has some number (or other special char) it will cut earlier..

Comment: If it's a Bash variable, `"${somevar%%[0-9]*}"` - look for answers about Bash parameter expansion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Preferred Alternative

We could simply [modify the rpm query](http://rpm5.org/docs/api/queryformat.html) to only output the name.

```
rpm -qa --queryformat "%{NAME}\n"
```

**Or we can get dirty with a regex**

Not exactly "straight forward" but here is a sed regex that should be able to do it.

```
sed -e 's/\([^\.]*\).*/\1/;s/-[0-9]*$//' <<< "perl-Text-ParseWords-3.30-1.fc22.i686"
```

This should handle everything except for in there is a period in the package name (I don't even think that is allowed).

**Quick breakdown**

- `s/\([^\.]*\).*/\1/` grab everything before the first period. So `perl-Text-ParseWords-3.30-1.fc22.i686` becomes `perl-Text-ParseWords-3`
- `s/-[0-9]*$//`get rid of that trailing `-` and first version digit. So `perl-Text-ParseWords-3` becomes `perl-Text-ParseWords`.

Comment: +1 for the `rpm` command.  I think that should be listed first.  :)

Comment: +1 for `rpm -qa --queryformat "%{NAME}\n"` that is the right way to do it. I have a package called `xmms2-core` so don't split on the number.

Comment: @hschou the sed expression should still work on xmms2-core. `-[0-9]*$` should only grab hyphen followed by numbers not letters to the EOL.

Comment: I had no idea I could format the rpm query like that. As a matter of fact that is ideal to my need. I will need the regex as well as I am parsing name of RPMS in a directory as well. Thanks for providing both!

Answer (score 3):

Directly in bash:

```
a='perl-Text-ParseWords-3.30-1.fc22.i686'
r='(^[^0-9]+)'
[[ $a =~ $r ]]

echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]%?}"
```